# Python3 IDLE dies with "Invalid host"

Tags: python, python-idle

IDLE will not start on my computer. It immediately dies raising OSError and prints the following crash information:

```
** Invalid host:  ('192.168.2.254', 47392)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 1516, in main
    shell = flist.open_shell()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 331, in open_shell
    if not self.pyshell.begin():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 1049, in begin
    client = self.interp.start_subprocess()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 465, in start_subprocess
    self.rpcclt.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/rpc.py", line 544, in accept
    raise OSError
OSError
```

As it happens, the address shown is my subnet interface. Looking inside `File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/rpc.py", line 544, in accept`, I see that it only accepts connections from LOCALHOST. My question is, if not connecting from localhost is a problem, then why is it choosing to connect to itself from that interface and how do I correct it?

Comment: (A python 'crash' is when the program hangs or stops without an exception.) This is the first report I know of with that error, so it seems related to your system.  If the address is always one you trust, you could try changing either LOCALHOST or the if condition on line 540.  In 3.8.6, '127.0.0.1' is hard-coded in pyshell 60, rpc 71, and run 39.  Since pyshell 'calls' on that address, I don't know why the listener gets a different address.  I believe the check is so that outsiders cannot connect and run python code on your system.

Comment: I have seen one other mention of this problem, with no solution offered. I have been examining my network configuration but can't find anything obvious. Currently, I suspect my systemd of mischief, but I can't prove anything. If I find anything interesting I will post in case anyone else experiences this problem.

Comment: I can now verify that this is not an issue with IDLE. I opened 2 terminals, and on one I typed `tcplisten -irv 127.0.0.1 6543`. On another terminal, I typed `tcpconnect -irv 127.0.0.1 6543`. The verbose output from `tcplisten` indicated that, even though it was listening on localhost, it received a connection from 192.168.2.254.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a masquerading issue. In this case, there was a firewall rule in place as follows:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

This was causing connections from 127.0.0.1 to be masqueraded as 192.168.2.254. The rule was removed and replaced with more specific forwarding rules and the problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you for posting.  What file is that?  I want to add this to the IDLE doc as another possible starting problem.

Comment: The iptables rules? They could be found anywhere. In my case they were added manually and made persistent with the netfilter-persistent service. If you want to add that to the documentation, I would mention it in the abstract as "misconfigured masquerading rules". Perhaps make a mention of how to diagnose it using my procedure in the comment above regarding tcplisten/tcpconnect.